# How can I find the xth digit of the yst integer in a list in Python?

Tags: python

I'm sorry if this is a very simple question, but I can't find an answer to it by searching the site, nor can I find one on YouTube. I just want something like this:

```
a = [12, 45, 15, 213, 1]
```

and I want to be able to find the value of say the 2nd element's 2nd digit (which would be 5)

Edit: Changed typo in expected behavior

Comment: What is the purpose of getting that value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using idexing you can get that

```
>>> str(a[1])[1]
'5'
>>>
```

Comment: @ChristianDean: Yes , chaged my answer

Comment: Thank you, any idea how I can get the length of an element so I can make sure if the value is bigger than the length, I can have it skip the line so the program doesn't crash?

Comment: `len(a) ` will give length of list , if you want get length of individual digit `len(str(a[0]))`

Comment: @Improbablyaskingforhelp : Glad to hear that was helpful. Please update post as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: the output here would not be `'4'` it would be `'5'`, since indexing starts at 0.

Comment: @9.0: Yes , it was edited by somebody. Changed properly now

Comment: The question said ` 2nd element's 2nd digit (which would be 4)`.

Comment: Sorry your answer is right.  I did not read the code Improbablyaskingforhelp properly I read what he asked for.  Specifically the digit 4 part.   It wasn't me who downvoted you though.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want to get the last digit.

```
a = [12, 45, 15, 213, 1]
print(a[1]%10) # 5
```

The index starts from zero so for n: `n -> n-1`

For each and every element in list.

```
print(list(map(lambda k:k%10, a))) # [2, 5, 5, 3, 1]
```